# Flutter Listview not updating list items on UI

Tags: database, flutter, listview, dart, flutter-desktop

I'm working on a flutter app and using ListView.builder widget to show my data. I'm fetching data from database and showing it in listview. After i modify single listitem i want to refresh whole listview widget.
Currently the problem is that data which i am passing to listview widget is updating accordingly but not updating on UI.
Here is the screenshot of method in which i am fetching data from database and updating listview

[image]

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: @Dev94, Are you definitely calling setState()? Or you using FutureBuilder?

Comment: I'm using FutureBuilder(), I tried both way, with and without setState() but not woring at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a streamBuilder for fetching the data and your method for fetching the data should be as follows :

```
Stream<List<Map<String,dynamic>>> fetchTimeLine() async* {
 while(true) {
   //first mention how much time to wait before fetching again I am using 10 
   // secs
   await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10));
   try {
      List<Map<String,dynamic>> allRows = await dbHelper.queryAllRows();
      yield allRows ; 
   } 
   finally {
      print('closed');
   }
 }
}
```